# Best Practice FastAPI - including routers

Tags: python-3.x, routes, fastapi

[FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#the-main-fastapi) states adding routers like so:

```
from .routers import items, users

app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_query_token)])

ROUTE_BASE = config("APP_URL")
app.include_router(users.router, prefix=ROUTE_BASE) 
app.include_router(items.router, prefix=ROUTE_BASE)
```

However, the current app I'm working on is getting quite large.

Is there anything to be cognizant of if we were to switch to adding our routes to the following:

```
from controllers.test import test_router
from controllers.prospect import prospect_router

ROUTE_BASE = config("APP_URL")
app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_query_token)]) 
routers = [test_router, prospect_router]
for router in routers:
    app.include_router(router=router, prefix=ROUTE_BASE)
```

Both methods work. I'm looking to see what other people have tried as I'm trying to keep my code dry by not continually repeating include_router(....)

Comment: There's not really a difference in what those two do, so either would work just fine - not sure what the problem would be with either case (you can also create a base APIRouter and register the other routers under that one, to avoid having to give a prefix to each router when you include it).

Answer (score 4):

Specifically, there is no difference in your approach, but (speaking from my own experience in managing current projects) when including new routers, it is convenient to give them individual prefixes, as well as create new sections for the Swagger (OpenAPI) such as:

```py
app.include_router(users.router, prefix="/users", tags=["Users"]) 
app.include_router(items.router, prefix="/items", tags=["Items"])
```

[image]